# Using FOR loop in R to find and replace medians in .csv file

Tags: r

I am new on here and new to R.
I have looked through the questions on here and cant find one that can help me.
So apologies here if I am just searching the wrong thing.

I am using the following code to help me find the medians of each column, there are 195 colums in the data.  I am using `na.rm = True`.
 Then trying to replace the NAs with the new calculated median.

I have used several different ways and keep getting stuck.  Any advise would be good.

```
dataset <- list.files(path = getwd(), pattern = "*.csv", all.files = T )
n <- length(dataset)

for (i in 1:n) {
  cat("\n",i)
  z <- median(dataset, na.rm = TRUE)
  dataset[is.na(dataset)] <- z
  return(dataset)
  write.csv(Filename, file = "Filename.csv")
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is a far simpler way of doing this, using `apply`

```
apply(dataset, 2, median, na.rm = TRUE)
```

The `2` simply says apply your function to columns rather than rows

Comment: It simply computes the medians but doesn't do the replacement of the NA.

Comment: perhaps I misunderstood the question

Answer (score 0):

With tidyverse, no need for a loop :

```
data %>% mutate_all(funs(ifelse(is.na(.),median(.,na.rm=TRUE),.)))
```

Or shorter :

```
data %>% mutate_all(funs(coalesce(.,median(.,na.rm=TRUE))))
```

Comment: or even simpler: `data %>% mutate_all(funs(replace_na(., median(., na.rm=TRUE))))`

Comment: @Shinobi_Atobe Generates :``Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: pas de m<e9>thode pour 'replace_na' applicable pour un objet de classe "c('double', 'numeric')".`

Comment: @Shibo_Atobe It was a problem of package version : I was using tidyr 0.7, it does work with **0.8**. Function `replace_na` was enhanced

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues with your code:
Your first command

```
dataset <- list.files(path = getwd(), pattern = "*.csv", all.files = T )
```

returns a list of filenames. Therefore, if you would want to process all your files you would need to call a function like `read.csv` inside your for loop. Your code example tries to calculate the median of the list of filenames.

Also, you specify the loop index i, but then you don't use it inside the for loop to access the right element of your filename list.

Inside your loop, you would therefore need a line like:

```
data <- read.csv(dataset[[i]])
```

Also, your to do the median imputation, you need to apply the median function row wise,
using a function like `lapply` or the tidyverse approach as in Nicolas2's answer.

Your return statement is not necessary as this is no function. Your `write.csv` function
expects a variable called "Filename", which is nowhere defined.
It should read like

```
write.csv(data, file = dataset[[i]]])
```

(provided you read in the files as "data" in your for loop).

All together, something like this should work:

```
dataset <- list.files(path = getwd(), pattern = "*.csv", all.files = T )
n <- length(dataset)

for (i in 1:n) {
  cat("\n",i)
  data <- read.csv(dataset[[i]])

  #from Nicolas2's answer   
  data <- data %>% mutate_all(funs(ifelse(is.na(.),median(.,na.rm=TRUE),.)))

  # uncomment the following line only if you are sure that you have a backup
  # of your original files as this may overwrite the original files
  # write.csv(data, file = dataset[[i]]) 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice and pointing out the mistakes.  Paired with Nicola2s answer it was brilliant and a great help.